# QtCore.Qt.Key_ doesnt seem to work

Tags: python, pyqt4, keypress, qtgui

This is my keyPressEvent

```
def keyPressEvent(self , e): 
    key = e.key()
    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
         self.close()
    elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_A:
         print 'Im here'
```

However if I click on A , it doesn't print. However the window is closing if I click on Escape.Where am I going wrong?

EDIT:

Basically I have a window with a lineedit and a pushbutton. I want to link the button to a function by clicking on Enter, lets say fun. This is my code

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui , QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example , self).__init__()
        self.window()

    def window(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Trial')

        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.text = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.first = QtGui.QPushButton('Button')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text , 0 , 0)    
        self.layout.addWidget(self.first , 1 , 0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.first.clicked.connect(self.fun)
        self.show()

    def fun(self):
        //do something


    def keyPressEvent(self , e):
        key = e.key()
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter:
            self.fun()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would add more keys later on. But none of them except Escape are working/

Comment: Can you add more context? The snippet that you've posted looks ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is called [`keyPressEvent`](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.keyPressEvent), not `KeyPressEvent`.

---

It seems that your `QLineEdit` is stealing your `KeyPress` events. If handling the enter key from the line edit is all you want to do, you could connect the `returnPressed` signal to `self.fun`:

```
self.text.returnPressed.connect(self.fun)  # in PySide
```

Otherwise, you will have to mess around with [event filters](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QObject.installEventFilter). I'll try posting some code later on.

---

Your final edit made it clearer. You can safely drop `keyPressEvent` and just use:

```
self.text.returnPressed.connect(self.fun)
self.button.clicked.connect(self.fun)
```

What a messy answer this turned out to be :)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo . I actually meant keyPressEvent only.Ive edited it also.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I think that was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You are making the GUI application, right? if yes then printing like that will print in the console. try this...

```
QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self,"hello","I m here")
```

Comment: Yes , it doesnt print anything then also